# Python Pickle File from Linux Incompatible with Mac?

Tags: python, linux, macos, python-3.x, pickle

I am trying to pickle the state of a Python (Python3.5) instance with the code:

```
g = open(file_name, 'wb')
pickle.dump(network, g)
g.close()
```

When I run this on my mac locally, the pickle file looks like ...

```
8003 6366 696e 6e65 6761 6e2e 6e65 7477
6f72 6b0a 4e65 7477 6f72 6b0a 7100 2981
7101 7d71 0228 580c 0000 006e 6575 726f
...
```

And when I run it in a docker container ...

```
S'<'
p18
NNNI-1
I-1
I0
tp19
bI00
...
```

Is this a linux/mac conflict or is something else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the `protocol` version, to make sure both machines are using the same version:

```
pickle.dump(network, g, protocol=4)
```

Comment: @JHoward don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you